# semicolon pausing in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Why does this shell script:

```
$ curl -d "asd" 0.0.0.0/abc & echo "abc";
```

results in me having to press <kbd>enter</kbd> before it enters the shell again. The `curl` is just a post request to a simple web server which returns `abc`.

However, this script does not require me to press enter before entering the shell again

```
$ echo "abc" & echo "abc"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you're seeing.

Comment: It doesn't require you to press enter. Only if you'd like to have a new prompt. Try giving another command instead of pressing just enter. It has nothing to do with the semicolon, but more to do with the single ampersand.

Comment: is it a timing issue where you have a shell prompt but don't see it ahead of the `abc` echo result?  Try entering `date` when you appear not to have a shell prompt...

Comment: Try `{ sleep 0.2; echo "abc"; } & echo "abc"` to have the same effect. You maybe want `&&` instead of `&` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` sends the `curl` command to the background, where it will run whenever it runs, the shell will not wait for it (it does print the job number and PID). Instead the shell goes on to run `echo`, which, since it's builtin, may well run faster than `curl`, so the shell finishes with `echo` and prints the prompt *before* `curl` gets to produce any output.

E.g. the output I get with Bash:

```
bash ~ $ curl -d "asd" 0.0.0.0/abc & echo "abc";
[1] 26757
abc
bash ~ $ curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 80: Connection refused
```

There's the prompt on the start of the last line.

Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> here has the shell print another prompt, at which point it also checks if the background job has completed, and prints a note about that:

```
[1]+  Exit 7                  curl -d "asd" 0.0.0.0/abc
bash ~ $
```

Now, I'm not sure what exactly it is you're doing, but having background jobs that print to the terminal is a bit awkward because of this, so you might want to redirect the output of `curl` elsewhere, or run it in the foreground. E.g. `curl something; echo curl done` would run `curl` first, then `echo`, and `curl something && echo curl done` would only run `echo` if `curl` doesn't fail.